# CakePHP - Call model function from another function within in the same model

Tags: php, cakephp, model

I've got a CakePHP model with a few functions in it working well.  Now I'm trying to write a new function that uses a few of the functions I've already written.  Seems like it should be easy but I can't figure out the syntax. How do I call these functions I've already written within my new one?

Example:

```
<?php
public function getHostFromURL($url) {
    return parse_url( $http.$url, PHP_URL_HOST );
}
public function getInfoFromURL($url) {
    $host = getHostFromURL($url);
    return $host;
}
```

Result:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function getHostFromURL() in /var/www/cake/app/Model/Mark.php on line 151

I also tried something like:

```
<?php
public function getHostFromURL($url) {
    return parse_url( $http.$url, PHP_URL_HOST );
}
public function getInfoFromURL($url) {
    $host = this->Mark->getHostFromURL($url);
    return $host;
}
```

But got the same result.

Obviously my functions are much more complicated than this (otherwise I'd just reuse them) but this is a good example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to call the other function like:

```
$host = $this->getHostFromURL($url);
```

Comment: Perfect.  I new to all this and couldn't figure out the right syntax and Google searches weren't helping.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If the function is in the same controller you access functions using

`$this->functionName` syntax.

You have wrong syntax below:

```
public function getInfoFromURL($url) {
    $host = this->Mark->getHostFromURL($url);
    return $host;
}
```

Should be:

```
public function getInfoFromURL($url) {
        $host = $this->getHostFromURL($url);
        return $host;
    }
```

If getFromHostUrl method is in the current class.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php